# Use cases of [ordered], the new PowerShell 3.0 feature

Tags: powershell, dictionary, powershell-3.0

PowerShell 3.0 CTP1 introduces a new feature `[ordered]` which is somewhat a shortcut for `OrderedDictionary`. I cannot imagine practical use cases of it. Why is this feature really useful? Can somebody provide some useful examples?

Example: this is, IMHO, rather demo case than practical:

```
$a = [ordered]@{a=1;b=2;d=3;c=4}
```

(I do not mind if it is still useful, then I am just looking for other useful cases).

I am not looking for use cases of `OrderedDictionary`, it is useful, indeed. But we can use it directly in v2.0 (and I do a lot). I am trying to understand why is this new feature `[ordered]` needed in addition.

---

### Collected use cases from answers:

```
$hash = [ordered]@{}
```

is shorter than

```
$hash = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary
```

N.B. `ordered` is not a real shortcut for the type. `New-Object ordered` does not work.

N.B. 2: But this is still a good shortcut because (I think, cannot try) it creates typical for PowerShell case insensitive dictionary. The equivalent command in v2.0 is too long, indeed:

```
New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary]([System.StringComparer]::OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

Comment: Actually, it is `$hash = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary`

Comment: Thank you, corrected. So yes, it saves time on typing. But is that all?

Comment: But then what about `[xml]`, `[datetime]`, `[hashtable]` and so many others including `[int]` - they are called accelerators after all.

Comment: Yes, but this accelerator is different from the mentioned. It is not a shortcut for a type. But it uses the same syntax. This is confusing. And the only real use case so far when it accelerates is `[ordered]@{}` with an **empty** hash table (I do not consider example with hardcoded values as really useful). I would not add a feature only for this. I must be missing something else useful, that is why I asked the question.

Comment: Maybe wait till the final version? It is CTP now, after all.

Comment: `Ordered` with hardcoded values would be useful is [this is resolved](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/680572/the-property-parameter-of-new-object-should-be-idictionary-not-hashtable). But until then `[ordered]@{}` (with empty hashes) seems to be the only useful case. This answer is accepted.

Comment: After playing with `[ordered]` I finally find it very useful. Yet another use case is, say, "PSON" (JSON-like data in PowerShell). I do not like though this verbose and confusing (as we saw) syntax `[ordered]@{...}`.

Comment: It's worth noting too that this is a special case for PowerShell, as is `[PSCustomObject]@{}`. It's not simply casting from Hashtable (which wouldn't work anyway because the Hashtable would have already lost the order). You can prove this by trying to use `@{}` and `[Ordered]` in separate assignments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First I will start by asking - Why not have them?

I can think of a use case in my project where we use Powershell scripts for build and deploy and yml for config ( using https://github.com/scottmuc/PowerYaml )

The config from yml is read in as hashtables. The tasks are specified in the yml like deploy to database, deploy to iis, deploy service and so on. I would like to do the database deploy and then website deploy so that I can avoid iisreset afterwards. Currently I have to explicitly look at that. Now, I can have an Ordered hash table and specify the deploy database first and hence it happens first.

Snippet:

```
function Convert-YamlMappingNodeToHash($node)
{
    $hash = @{}
    $yamlNodes = $node.Children

    foreach($key in $yamlNodes.Keys)
    {
        $hash[$key.Value] = Explode-Node $yamlNodes[$key]
    }
    return $hash
}
```

Now the `$hash =@{}` become `$hash=[ordered]@{}`

I don't know how this means for a bloated product. OrderedDictionary is there in .NET ( I have lots of use cases for it in programming ) and they have just added an accelerator for it.

Comment: "Why not have them?"... If this is the only reason, then this is a way to the bloated product, perhaps.

Comment: 1 use case is recorded ([ordered]@{} vs. New-Object System.Collections.OrderedDictionary). Juat a note: I would like to have an accelerator [list] for ArrayList in the same way. Actually I use ArrayList more often than OrderedDictionary. Perhaps it's only me, of course.

Comment: So you were asking the question from the angle that when there is New-Object System.Collections.OrderedDictionary why have ordered now?

Comment: is this really a shortcut? I do not have v3.0 yet to try. Does this work: `New-Object ordered`?

Comment: "when there is New-Object System.Collections.OrderedDictionary why have ordered now?" - yes, this is one reason.

Comment: Nope, errors out - New-Object : Cannot find type [ordered]: make sure the assembly containing this type is loaded. Weird...considering how stuff like new-object hashtable etc. work.

Answer (score 14):

This is actually particularly useful for creating on-the-fly objects sorta like how you would use ExpandoObject in C# or dynamic objects in JavaScript. The problem with doing this in prior versions of PowerShell is that `@{}` (which becomes a regular `HashTable`) loses your ordering of keys so it's a huge PITA to display these to the screen.

Consider this.

```
foreach ($row in import-csv blah.csv) {

  # In v3: $obj = [Ordered]@{

  $obj = @{
    Name      = $row.Name
    Exists    = Test-Path $row.FileName
    OtherProp = 123
    Blah      = "derp"
    Timestamp = Get-Date
  }

  New-Object PSObject -Property $Obj

}
```

In PowerShell v2, the column order is unpredictable because the `Hashtable` does not retain the order of the keys. In PowerShell v3, if you used the `[Ordered]` type, the key order is retained, making the quick and dirty PowerShell syntax almost as convenient as JSON for quickly building up object structures without all the overhead and performance issues associated with `Add-Member` or `Select-Object`.

Not coincidentally, there is another addition to PowerShell v3. Similar to `[Ordered]` you can actually specify `[PSCustomObject]` instead. This will create an actual `PSObject` right from the start instead of requiring a separate call to `New-Object`. I can't say for sure but I am pretty sure that `[Ordered]` was a side effect of the changes they made to the parser to make that happen. If they were just doing a conversion from a regular `Hashtable`, there'd be no way to restore the original order of the keys.

Comment: that last bit, using `[PSCustomObject]` to make "object literals", is gold. So much nicer than `New-Object psobject -Prop`. You should add a code example of that so people don't miss it. Even though I guess it's not answering the question.

Answer (score 2):

This is useful for doing a SQL join (aka merging or zipping) two data files.  Maybe the files are CSV or JSON.

You'd want to build a hashtable from the first file, merge in or use data from the second file, then stream the changes back out to disk or to the next step of the script.

With [ordered] you can keep the same order of the original file, but still use it like a hashtable.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen it used in powershell scripts that build tabs of information and sort the tabs. For example, retrieving hard drive information from several servers, each server in its own tab, then sorting the tabs by server name before saving. The "tab sort" code looks like this:

```
$i=0;$wb.Worksheets | %{$i++;[ordered]@{$_.name=$i}}
```

-Gill