# How do I create an anonymous object in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I want to create an object of arbitrary values, sort of like how I can do this in C#

```
var anon = new { Name = "Ted", Age = 10 };
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can do any of the following, in order of easiest usage:

1. **Use Vanilla Hashtable with PowerShell 5+**

   *In PS5, a vanilla hash table will work for most use cases*

   ```cs
   $o = @{ Name = "Ted"; Age = 10 }
   ```
2. **Convert Hashtable to `PSCustomObject`**

   *If you don't have a strong preference, just use this where vanilla hash tables won't work:*

   ```cs
   $o = [pscustomobject]@{
       Name = "Ted";
       Age = 10
   }
   ```
3. **Using `Select-Object` cmdlet**

   ```cs
   $o = Select-Object @{n='Name';e={'Ted'}},
                      @{n='Age';e={10}} `
                      -InputObject ''
   ```
4. **Using `New-Object` and `Add-Member`**

   ```cs
   $o = New-Object -TypeName psobject
   $o | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value 'Ted'
   $o | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Age -Value 10
   ```
5. **Using `New-Object` and hashtables**

   ```cs
   $properties = @{
       Name = "Ted";
       Age = 10
   }
   $o = New-Object psobject -Property $properties;
   ```

#### Note: Objects vs. HashTables

Hashtables are just dictionaries containing `keys` and `values`, meaning you might not get the expected results from other PS functions that look for `objects` and `properties`:

```
$o = @{ Name="Ted"; Age= 10; }
$o | Select -Property *
```

#### Further Reading

- [4 Ways to Create PowerShell Objects](https://ridicurious.com/2018/10/15/4-ways-to-create-powershell-objects/)
- [Everything you wanted to know about `hashtables`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-hashtable?view=powershell-7.1)
- [Everything you wanted to know about `PSCustomObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.1)

Answer (score 35):

Try this:

```
PS Z:\> $o = @{}
PS Z:\> $o.Name = "Ted"
PS Z:\> $o.Age = 10
```

Note: You can also include this object as the `-Body` of an `Invoke-RestMethod` and it'll serialize it with no extra work.

### Update

Note the comments below. This creates a hashtable.

Comment: I like do it like this: `$o = [ordered]@{ Name = "Ted"; Age = 10 }`

Comment: @CB. might want to clarify what `[ordered]` is for in that instance.

Comment: The "[ordered]" is a type accelerator; it's new as of PowerShell 3.0. It's just saying the thing to the right is an [OrderedDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7802406/530545).  [You don't need it, but it's nice](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/09/30/use-powershell-to-create-ordered-dictionary/).

Comment: It's not custom object. It's a hashtable, check this `$o.GetType()` out. And in strict PS mode it won't work, only `$o['Name']`.

Comment: PLEASE beware that [the answer by prampe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59107772/177710) shows how to do this in almost the exact same syntax the OP hoped for: `$anon = @{ Name="Ted"; Age= 10; }`. This is possible from **PowerShell 5** upwards.

Comment: As many noted... this creates an hashtable and not a object... the above answer by @KilyMit gaves the correct answer

Comment: I've finally got around to switching to the correct answer! Sorry!

Answer (score 7):

With PowerShell 5+
Just declare as:

```js
    $anon = @{ Name="Ted"; Age= 10; }
```

[image: Example]