# Explicitly return value in multiline calculated property in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, psobject

In PS, when using [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7#parameters), the `-Property` param "specifies the properties to select":

> The value of the Property parameter can be a new *calculated property*. To create a calculated, property, use a hash table.
>
> Valid keys are:
>
> - **Name**: `<string>`
> - **Expression**: `<string>` or `<script block>`

As an starting point, here's an [anonymous object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56813241/1366033)

```cs
$person = [pscustomobject]@{
    FirstName = "Kyle";
    LastName = "Mit"
}
```

The following calculated property works just fine:

```cs
$person | Select-Object 'FirstName', 'LastName', 
            @{
                Name="FullName";
                Expression= { "$($_.FirstName) $($_.LastName)" }
            }
```

Which correctly returns the following:

```
FirstName LastName FullName
--------- -------- --------
Kyle      Mit      Kyle Mit
```

**However**, I'm trying to build a calculated property that takes some complicated logic and requires multiple lines to implement.  As soon as I have another return value inside the expression both values are returned.

So the following query will return `FullName` as `{ false, "Kyle Mit" }`

```cs
$person | Select-Object 'FirstName', 'LastName', 
            @{
                Name="FullName";
                Expression= { 
                    "test" -eq "example"
                    return "$($_.FirstName) $($_.LastName)" 
                }
            }
```

Which returns the following:

```
FirstName LastName FullName         
--------- -------- --------         
Kyle      Mit      {False, Kyle Mit}
```

But I'm attempting to explicitly return just the last statement.  Delimiting with `;` or using `return` doesn't seem to help.

Any ideas?

Comment: not sure what is your logic... I mean... u're testing something then returning something... why to do that that way? use `if`? and return 2 different answers?

Comment: @FlashThunder, agreed - it's a weird case. When [using `-matches`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59900840/1366033), powershell will [create an automatic variable named `$Matches`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#matches) as a side-effect.  So the original expression will return `true` or `false`, but what I'm after is the variable introduced once that's called.

Comment: For `-matches` you probably still want to use `if`: `if($something -match "regexp") { $Matches[0] } else { '' }`, as otherwise the `Matches` variable might return unrelated data in case of no match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just toss out the unwanted expression result with `Out-Null`.:

```
$person | Select-Object 'FirstName', 'LastName',
             @{
                 Name="FullName";
                 Expression= {
                     "test" -eq "example" | out-null
                    return "$($_.FirstName) $($_.LastName)"
                 }
             }
```