# How to add same keys with different values to a hashtable in powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, powercli

Here is the code where i used array of hashtables

```
$podnumbers = @(1,3,1)

$podInfo = $null
$buffer = 0
$podarray = foreach ($pd in $podnumbers) {
    $podinfo = @()
    for($i=0;$i -lt $pd;$i = $i+1) {
    $pod = Read-Host -Prompt "Assign the pod numbers for",$esxarray[$buffer]
    Write-Output `n
    }
    @{$pd = $pod}
$buffer = $buffer + 1
}
```

Inputs I gave for $pod is 1 = 1 ; 3 = 2,4,6 ; 1 = 3

I want my arrays of hashtable to be like below,

```
Key : 1
Value : 1
Name : 1

Key : 3
Value : 2,4,6
Name : 3

Key : 1
Value : 3
Name : 1
```

But the actual output I got is,

```
Key : 1
Value : 1
Name : 1

Key : 3
Value : 2
Name : 3

Key : 3
Value : 4
Name : 3

Key : 3
Value : 6
Name : 3

Key : 1
Value : 3
Name : 1
```

Comment: You don't - either add/modify the existing key'd entry or find something other than a dictionary type to hold your data :)

Comment: Since you seem to configure ESX Pods, maybe [edit] the question and explain what you are trying to do. It's likely you need to invert the keys and values.

Comment: edited my objective

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add multiple values to the same key, you need to test for whether the key is already present and act accordingly:

```
$keys = 1,2,3,1
$value = 'a value'
$hashtable = @{}

foreach($key in $keys){
  if(-not $hashtable.ContainsKey($key)){
    # First time we see this key, let's make sure the value is a resizable array
    $hashtable[$key] = @()
  }

  # Now we can safely add values regardless of whether the key already exists
  $hashtable[$key] += $value
}
```

Comment: as per my requirement i wanna add key '1' twice or thrice with different values for each '1' key.
eg: $hashtable = @{1 = 'host1' ; 2 = 'host2','host4'; 1 = 'host3'}

Comment: @DjangoUnchained yes? Nothing stops you from doing that using the above approach

Answer (score 1):

To complement the answer from [@Matthias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen):
You can't have duplicate keys in a [hash table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7). This is by design. Hash tables contain a list of unique keys based on a [binary search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) where each key is linked to a specific object (value).

### There are *two* workarounds:

#### 1. add an array of values to a specific hash table key:

```
$Keys = 1,2,2,3
$Values = 'a'..'d'
$HashTable = @{}
$i = 0
foreach($key in $Keys){ [array]$HashTable[$Key] += $Values[$i++] }
```

**Iterating**
The disadvantage is that you lose the order of the items (regardless if you use an [ordered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7802406/1701026) dictionary simply because some values share a single key).

```
Foreach ($Key in $Hashtable.Keys) {
    Foreach ($Value in @($Hashtable[$Key])) {
        Write-Host $Key '=' $Value
    }
}
```

```
3 = d
2 = b
2 = c
1 = a
```

**Searching**
The advantage is that the items are binary indexed and therefor quickly found.

```
$SearchKey = 2
Foreach ($Value in @($Hashtable[$SearchKey])) {
    Write-Host $SearchKey '=' $Value
}
```

```
2 = b
2 = c
```

#### 2. or you might create a list (array) of hash tables ([Key Value Pairs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2?view=netcore-3.1))

```
$Keys = 1,2,2,3
$Values = 'a'..'d'
$i = 0
$KeyValuePairs = foreach($key in $keys){ @{ $Key = $Values[$i++] } }
```

**Iterating**
The advantage is that the items will stay in order.
<sup>(Note that you have to invoke the [`GetEnumerator()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable.getenumerator?view=netcore-3.1) method twice)</sup>

```
$KeyValuePairs.GetEnumerator().GetEnumerator() | Foreach-Object {
    Write-Host $_.Key '=' $_.Value
}
```

```
1 = a
2 = b
2 = c
3 = d
```

**Searching**
The disadvantage is that searching for the items is slower and little more comprehensive.

```
$SearchKey = 2
$KeyValuePairs.GetEnumerator().GetEnumerator() | 
    Where-Object Key -eq $SearchKey | Foreach-Object {
    Write-Host $_.Key '=' $_.Value
}
```

```
2 = b
2 = c
```

Comment: What if I want to add 3 values to key(3), that's how it should be. eg: for key 2 = 2 values will be added and for key 4 = 4 values will be added

Comment: That is already shown in the above answer. To make this more clear; I have updated it with different values (you might change this to `'a'..'z'`, if you want to play with more key-values). Anyways, if it still doesn't answer what you are looking for, I recommend you to (re)create  the question with a [mcve] (like the above examples) and an expected output (list of key-value pairs) as I either I still do not understand you, or you starting to contradict yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing this in a separate answer as your new redefined objective more specific than the initial question appeared. Instead, each response should be assigned to a the concerned podnumber.

**Script:**

```
$podnumbers = @(1,3,1)
$Inputs = 1,2,4,6,3
$c = 0
$podarray = foreach ($pd in $podnumbers) {
    $podinfo = @{}
    for($i=0; $i -lt $pd; $i = $i+1) {
        # $pod = Read-Host -Prompt "Assign the pod numbers for",$esxarray[$buffer]
        [array]$podinfo[$pd] += $Inputs[$c++]
    }
    $podinfo
}
$podarray
```

**Output:**

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
1                              {1}
3                              {2, 4, 6}
1                              {3}
```

Comment: thank you iRon, i tried the above script but write-output of $podarray was empty in cli

Comment: I have tested again and for me, the above example works with both Windows PowerShell 5.1 and PowerShell Core 7

Comment: the $podinfo outside the inner for loop i.e } $podinfo } does it needed there?

Comment: Just `$podinfo` is similar to [`Write-Output $podinfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output?view=powershell-7#description) it writes the data to the pipeline, and eventually *displays it*. Meaning, you might leave it out (if you do not want to display the results) or consider to pass it on to another cmdlet (but that is a complete different question). **Does it work now? Does it answer the question?**

Comment: it neither threw error nor displayed the results for Write-Output $podarray

Comment: I am about to give up: If you paste the content under **Script**, in the IDE or a fresh PowerShell console, you should see the content as shown under **Output**. This proves that `$podarray` contains the requested information.

Answer (score 0):

There's a simpler and faster way to do this: an array of hashtables. For this, I'll be using an 'ArrayList', which is a type of array that is not a fixed size.

ArrayLists keep PowerShell from having to recreate an array every time you want to add a new item, which is great for foreach operations.

I'm going to go ahead and just present a simple example instead of integrating it into your code. Given the age of this question, it's doubtful you still need it, so this is more for everyone else.

###### EXAMPLE CODE

```
# Make sure this is initialized outside BEFORE the foreach loop:
$arr = New-Object Collections.ArrayList
#OR
$arr = [Collections.ArrayList]::new()

# Normally the 'Add' method for ArrayList outputs the updated count,
# setting it to the $null variable prevents that.
$null = $arr.Add( @{foo='bar'} )
$null = $arr.Add( @{foo='test'} )
```

As for iterating over the resulting array, here are a few good ways of doing so:

###### PER-ITEM ITERATION

```
$arr.ForEach({$_.GetEnumerator()}).ForEach({
  "Key: " + $ht.Key; "Value: " + $ht.Value })

#OR

foreach ($ht in $arr) {
  "Key: " + $ht.Keys; "Value: " + $ht.Values }
```

###### *output:*

```
Key: foo
Value: bar
Key: foo
Value: test
```

###### PER-KEY ITERATION

```
foreach ($k in ($arr.Keys | Get-Unique)) {
  "Key: $k"; "Value(s): " + $arr.$k }
```

###### *output:*

```
Key: foo
Value(s): bar test
```

I'm deliberately avoiding using ForEach-Object in these examples due to its performance issues in every version of PowerShell (7.2.1 is the current version as of writing). You can read more about that [here](https://powershell.one/tricks/performance/pipeline).