# How to create arrays of hashtable in powershell?

Tags: arrays, powershell, hashtable

I have an hashtable with a below structure,

```
$podhashtable = @{2 = '1','2' ; 3 = '3','4','5' ; 1 = '6'}
```

Here is the code how I achieve the above hashtable,

```
$podnumbers = @(2,3,1)
$podInfo = @()
$podhashtable = [ordered]@{}
$buff = 0
foreach ($pd in $podnumbers) {
    #$podInfo = @()
    for($i=0;$i -lt $pd;$i = $i+1) {
    $pod = Read-Host -Prompt "Assign the pod numbers for",$esxarray[$buff]
    $podinfo += $pod
    }

$podInfoOb = New-Object PSObject –Property $podsets
$podsets = @{$pd = $podInfo}
$podhashtable += $podsets
$buff = $buff + 1
}
Write-Output $podhashtable
```

I'm trying to create array of hashtable like below,

```
$podhashtable = @{2 = '1','2'}, @{3 = '3','4','5'}, @{1 = '6'}
```

What is the best way to get the above array of hashtable?

Answer (score 0):

This question apparently refers to: [How to add same keys with different values to a hashtable in powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64592431/1701026)

I guess you want to do this:

```
$buff = 0
$podnumbers = @(2,3,1,2)
$podhashtable = foreach ($pd in $podnumbers) {
    $podInfo = @{}
    for($i=0; $i -lt $pd; $i = $i+1) {
        $pod = Read-Host -Prompt "Assign the pod numbers for" # , $esxarray[$buff]
        $podinfo[$i] = $pod
        # $podInfoOb = New-Object PSObject –Property $podsets
        $podInfo
        $buff = $buff + 1
    }
}
Write-Output $podhashtable
```

But I can't be sure as you didn't supply a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (please do so next time; e.g.: define `$esxarray` or leave it out).

Comment: Actually yes, but as per the question you referenced didn't satisfy my objective coz hashtable doesn't allow duplicate keys. Though of using arrays of hashtable so I can add duplicate keys with different values

Comment: I am not sure whether I understand what the issue remains. I have added a duplicate key (`$podnumbers = @(2,3,1,2)`) to the (updated) answer, which is based on [2. or you might create a list (array) of hash tables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64592431/1701026)

Comment: i have tried your method which allows adding duplicate keys but it merges the values of duplicate keys together, I wish to add duplicate keys with different values and represent the keys independently

Comment: You can do that by placing the `$podInfo` (and `$buff = $buff + 1`) inside the `for` loop. (I have updated the answer accordingly).